# Animated.Decay - formula to reach value

Tags: animation, react-native

I like the natural feel decay adds to my animations but the problem I have is that I can't get it to land on a whole number unlike the other animations.

Is there a vector math formula I can use to calc the deceleration value and velocity so that it does?

i.e. 
current animated value is 0.75
velocity = 2

Would like to animate to 2.0 so deceleration rate = ???